# Can't connect to localhost mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get my app working with docker but I am having trouble getting my database to display. It seems my laravel application itself can access it but I need to access it myself in order to troubleshoot issues.

The problem when I try to access localhost:4306 (the port of which the db is on). when I go to that in the browser it outputs:

```
    J���
5.7.22�
���X5g  ^A�яя�яБ����������8O?x
tdm�mysql_native_password���я„Got packets out of order
```

The db section of the .env is:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

the docker-compose is:

```
version: '3.2'

networks:
  laravel:


services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
```

and the Dockerfile referenced in the docker-compose.yml is:

```
    FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
# Setup GD extension
 RUN apk add --no-cache \
       freetype \
       libjpeg-turbo \
       libpng \
       freetype-dev \
       libjpeg-turbo-dev \
       libpng-dev \
     && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
       --with-freetype=/usr/include/ \
#      --with-png=/usr/include/ \ # No longer necessary as of 7.4; https://github.com/docker-library/php/pull/910#issuecomment-559383597
       --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ \
     && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
     && docker-php-ext-enable gd \
     && apk del --no-cache \
       freetype-dev \
       libjpeg-turbo-dev \
       libpng-dev \
     && rm -rf /tmp/*
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN chown -R 1000:www-data /var/www/html
```

Comment: Which charset has your database?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by charset

Comment: Why are you trying to open the MySQL connection port in your browser? Try using something like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to connect to database through HTTP protocol, that's why you are receiving that message.

You can connect to MySql database using phpMyAdmin (web client) or any installed MySql client.

- Docker has phpMyAdmin available: https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/
- There are many MySql Clients available. Just search in your favorite search engine by "mysql client" followed by the name of your Operating System.